# Rotating Circular Images

Tags: rotation

I am trying to create 5 circular images that would rotate around one larger, central circular image.

I'd like the rotation to stop if the cursor is hovered over any image, and have all images linkable to other pages.

I have the exterior images here:

http://codepen.io/chipower/pen/mysdh

Does anyone know how to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Use setInterval for the animation. This will call the same function every n milliseconds.

When the mouse hovers(jQuery.hover) then set a flag that the function SetInterval calls   to see if the angle of the item should be increased and layout redrawn.

If the flag is clear increase the angle and plot the new top, left of the css item to display in a circle.

```
    x = r * Math.cos(deg2Rad(a)) + cx;
    y = r * Math.sin(deg2Rad(a)) + cy;
```

where x,y are the required top, left CSS attributes a is the angle, r is the radius from the cx,cy center of the circle.

deg2Rad(a) converts degrees to radians

```
function deg2Rad(deg){
    return deg*Math.PI/180;
}
```

Your last point about making the images linkable is just standard HTML as you have at the moment just update the "#" to the correct url

Comment: Thanks. I had some help, and I have it running at http://www.admaticonsulting.com/test1, but, there is a jumping effect in Chrome and IE, and it's jittery in Firefox.